# Pull to dismiss ViewController - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I have a main controller (I call A) with some buttons and when I tap on one of them I present another ViewControllorer (I call B).
B is a UIViewcontroller that has a TableView inside.
I want to implement a "pull to dismiss": when I go to top of tableview scroll I want to dismiss viewcontroller (viewcontroller have to follow the finger to down).

I find some library on GitHub that implement this but I have a conflict because in one of this cell of tableview there is a horizontal scroll and when I swipe on this scroll controller dismiss.

My question is: Can you give me some tips for implement this mechanism without other library ("by hand")?

Comment: Have you tried with UIRefreshControl?  
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uirefreshcontrol
  UIRefreshControl is UIControl which is UIView. So if you're writing you're own UIRefreshControl then you should be able to change its animations and outlook.
The documentation describes how to use it.

Comment: I dont understand your answer. I have to dismiss controller not refresh

Comment: UIRefreshControl triggers its action on the pull. In the example code, there is function handleRefreshControl. You choose yourself what you want to do with that action. You can dismiss the ViewController.  Pop ViewController from navigationController, delegate feedback, etc. Be creative ;)

Comment: Yes I just tried it but first I dont show the loader of refresh (I tried to set isHidden = true but it dosent work) and second the closing transaction is too fast

Comment: first problem is resolved setting same tint color of background